# CSS Dropdown disapperas

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I have a problem with my dropdown menu. when i try to hover on item it works fine, but when i try to move cursor to second item in dropdown menu it disappears.
My code:

Code:

```css
nav.pc {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  top: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

nav.pc ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav.pc ul.menu {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  position: relative;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li.cur:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: .25em;
  background-color: #308cca;
  border-radius: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav.pc a {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .2em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  top: 3.5em;
  left: -4em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  width: 10em;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ecf0f1 transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -.7em;
  right: 2em;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: .1em solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.15);
  position: relative;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li a {
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  width: calc(100% - 3em);
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .2em;
  top: -.3em;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: .3em 0;
  width: 10em;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu li {
  display: block;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li.drop:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li.drop ul.dropdown li.sub:hover ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li:hover,
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:hover,
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu li:hover {
  color: #308cca;
}
```

```html
<nav class="pc">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">Dropdown&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-xs"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
        <li class="sub">
          <a href="#">Submenu</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Generic</a></li>
    <li class="cur"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I tryed almost everything but i can't figure out why is it doing this. And also it don't work only on sub-page, on index.html it works fine.

Comment: I have tested on Chrome, FireFox and Explorer. all of them worked without the issue you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the space between your `ul li a` and `ul li ul`. You defined `top: 3.5em;`. You could either remove the space or you give your `a` tag a transparent border:

```css
nav.pc{
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  top: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
nav.pc ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav.pc ul.menu{
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
nav.pc ul.menu li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
  position: relative;
}
nav.pc ul.menu li.cur:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: .25em;
  background-color: #308cca;
  border-radius: 1em;
  bottom: 1.5em;
}
nav.pc a{
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
nav.pc > ul.menu > li > a {
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .2em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  left: -4em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  width: 10em;
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ecf0f1 transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -.7em;
  right: 2em;
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li{
  color: black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: .1em solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.15);
  position: relative;
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:last-child{
  border: none;
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li a{
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  width: calc(100% - 3em);
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .2em;
  top: -.3em;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  padding: .3em 0;
  width: 10em;
}
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu li{
  display: block;
}
nav.pc ul.menu li.drop:hover ul.dropdown{
  display: block;
}
nav.pc ul.menu li.drop ul.dropdown li.sub:hover ul.submenu{
  display: block;
}
nav.pc ul.menu li:hover, nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:hover, nav.pc ul.menu 
ul.dropdown ul.submenu li:hover{
  color: #308cca;
}
```

```html
<nav class="pc">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">Dropdown&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-xs"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
        <li class="sub">
          <a href="#">Submenu</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Generic</a></li>
    <li class="cur"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**EDIT**

Ok got your problem, after you added the comment. Just add `position: relative; z-index: 1001;` to your `header`.

Comment: here it is [link](http://speedmine.eu/pointless) , on index it works, but try look at gallery and try to hover over the menu

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand, works fine on chrome ... I haven't any problems when I hover the submenu. The first one doesn't close. Which browser you have ?

```css
nav.pc{
        width: 100%;
        height: 3em;
        top: 1em;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    nav.pc ul{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu{
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu li{
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 3em;
        color: black;
        margin: 0 1.5em;
        transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
        position: relative;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu li.cur:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: .25em;
        background-color: #308cca;
        border-radius: 1em;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    nav.pc a{
        text-decoration: inherit;
        color: inherit;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        border-radius: .2em;
        padding: .3em 0;
        top: 3.5em;
        left: -4em;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        width: 10em;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown:before{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        border-color: transparent transparent #ecf0f1 transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: -.7em;
        right: 2em;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li{
        color: black;
        display: block;
        line-height: 2.5em;
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: .1em solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.15);
        position: relative;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:last-child{
        border: none;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li a{
        padding: 0 1.5em;
        width: calc(100% - 3em);
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ecf0f1;
        border-radius: .2em;
        top: -.3em;
        left: -100%;
        z-index: 5;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        padding: .3em 0;
        width: 10em;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu li{
        display: block;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu li.drop:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu li.drop ul.dropdown li.sub:hover ul.submenu{
        display: block;
    }
    nav.pc ul.menu li:hover, nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:hover, nav.pc ul.menu 
    ul.dropdown ul.submenu li:hover{
        color: #308cca;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="pc">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#">Dropdown&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-xs"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
                    <li class="sub">
                        <a href="#">Submenu</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option Four</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Generic</a></li>
            <li class="cur"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: i'm using chrome too, wait a moment, i'll upload it on my web and post the link here

Comment: here it is [link](http://speedmine.eu/pointless) , on index it works, but try look at gallery and try to hover over the menu

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav.pc {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  top: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

nav.pc ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav.pc ul.menu {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  position: relative;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li.cur:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: .25em;
  background-color: #308cca;
  border-radius: 1em;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav.pc a {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #308cca;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .2em;
  padding: 0;
  top: 3em;
  left: -4em;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  width: 10em;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ecf0f1 transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -.7em;
  right: 2em;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: .1em solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.15);
  position: relative;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li a {
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  width: calc(100% - 3em);
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: .2em;
  top: -.3em;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  padding: .3em 0;
  width: 10em;
}

nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu li {
  display: block;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li.drop:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li.drop ul.dropdown li.sub:hover ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}

nav.pc ul.menu li:hover,
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown li:hover,
nav.pc ul.menu ul.dropdown ul.submenu li:hover {
  color: #308cca;
}
```

```html
<nav class="pc">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">Dropdown&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-xs"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
        <li class="sub">
          <a href="#">Submenu</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Generic</a></li>
    <li class="cur"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```